# Are all connected graphs with Euler characteristics 2 planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have read proofs and descriptions stating that a planar connected graph have the Euler characteristic 2. I'm not sure if that statement is equivalent to "a connected graph with the Euler characteristic 2 have a planar embedding"?

I'm studying a math course where I'm supposed to show that a certain graph have a planar embedding, and I'm wondering if I can show it by using the Euler characteristics.

Comment: How do you define the Euler characteristic of a non-planar graph? The notion of faces in this case seems to be problematic

Comment: Ordinarily speaking the Euler characteristic of a graph is defined to be the number of vertices minus the number of edges. But in that case, every connected finite graph has Euler characteristic $\le 1$. So I'm not sure what this question could possibly mean.

Comment: @LeeMosher : You can define without much trouble the number of faces of a connected planar graph, and if you do this, every connected planar graph has indeed Euler characteristic 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the approach you are suggesting is that we usually don't know anything about the number of faces of a graph before we embed the graph. The only situation I can think of(there could be more) where this sort of argument could do anything would be if you were given a problem like

> "Let $G$ be a graph with $|V(G)|=n$, $|E(G)|=m$ and assume that it can be embedded without crossings on the surface $S_k$ with $r$ faces but not any surface of lesser genus. Is $G$ planar?"

Then you could calculate $n-m+r$ and if you got $2$ then we can conclude that $G$ is planar. Unless given the number of faces in a minimal embedding though, I see no way to use the Euler Characteristic to prove planarity.